# Add a template file to cms page Magento 2

Tags: magento2

How can I add a template file located under:
app/code/design/Smartwave/porto_child/Qx/Verkoopje/templates/laptop.phtml

Into a cms page?

I use the following code but it does not work

{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="verkoopje" template="Qx_Verkoopje::laptop.phtml"}}

Answer (score 1):

> Syntax to call Block-Template in CMS page:

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="[VendorName]_[ModuleName]::[TemplateFilePath].phtml"}}
```

> Forntend template file path:

```
app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/view/frontend/templates/file.phtml
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for awnsering, can you write out the templatepath location as in your example?

Comment: Hi, I've already mentioned template path on above answer (i.e. app/code/Qx/Verkoopje/view/frontend/templates/file.phtml)
I think you're working with Porto theme.

Comment: Yes to be used in the widget code. DO I need to register the block?